# simple maths problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

N locations are numbered from 0 to N-1. Given a int[] containing N elements. The i-th (0-based index) element of array is the number of persons who live near location i.One car can move to one location only.Now we have cars to be made where each car has basecost and cost of each seat so total car cost is basecost + X*seatcost.X is choosen to be any positive integer. (But remember that all the cars must have the same X.) I need to find minimum cost to be spent so that all people can have transport

Example :

array : {9, 4}

Basecost : 30

seatcost : 5

Answer is 150

As their are two locations. There are 9 persons living near location 0 and 4 persons living near location 1. It is optimal to buy two cars with 9 seats each and send a single car to each location. (Note that the carss we buy must all be of the same size. It is not allowed to buy one car with 9 and another with 4 seats.)

If in the example above basecost was 10 and seatcost was 5

Then ,result would be 105 because as basecost is lower. It is optimal to buy three cars with 5 seats each and send two cars to location 0 and one shuttle to location 1.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to stackoverflow.

Comment: @CODE I think its more of mathematics question rather than algorithmic one

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to calculate $c(X)$, the cost of a single car with $X$ seats.  The number of cars you need is $\sum_i \lceil \frac {n_i}X \rceil$ where $n_i$ is the population at location $i$.  Just loop over $X$ from $1$ to the maximum population of any location, add up the sum, and pick the best.

Comment: Could you provide an algo or a piece of code plz?

Comment: This is an algorithm.  The sum over $i$ is a loop.  Do you know how to calculate the ceiling function?

Comment: ya i know how to calculate ceil function .But I am bit confused with algorithm purposed.Could you provide a code in c++ or java?

Comment: @ Ross Millikan What is ni being used in your summation?Means at which location i you are talking about?

Comment: No, I don't speak either one.  The total cost of cars is the product of the number of cars times the cost of each one.  I showed how to compute the number of cars at each location.  Go through the locations and add them up-that is the total number of cars.  Multiply by cost per car and you get total cost.

Comment: Yes $n_i$ is the number at address $i$.  So $i$ ranges from $0$ to $N-1$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11972/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user3001932)

Comment: So can i say it as  sum of all array elements?

Comment: should not it be ni/X instead of X/ni ?

Comment: You are right in both the last two